# Magento 2: Create products attributes programatically, without install script

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

How to create product attributes in Magento 2 so it works in running script without install script

Comment: using custom script ?

Comment: My requirement is need to check before create product that attribute exist or not. If not then it should create first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a helper class (ProductAttribute.php) to check attribute exist or not, If not exist then it will create attribute.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

class ProductAttribute extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory
     */
    protected $eavEavSetupFactory;
    protected $eavConfig;
    protected $attributeSetFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavEavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,       
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->eavEavSetupFactory = $eavEavSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function createOrUpdateProductUDA($value, $input, $type) {

        $attributeCode = $this->getAttributeCode($value);

        // Check Attribute already exist or not
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
        if (!$attribute || !$attribute->getAttributeId()) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(
                __('Attribute with attributeCode "%1" does not exist.', $attributeCode)
            );

            return true;
        }

        /** @var ProductSetup $productSetup */
        $productSetup = $this->eavEavSetupFactory->create();

        $productEntity = $productSetup->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');
        $attributeSetId = $productSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($productEntity);

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        // print_r(get_class_methods($productSetup));
        $productSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            $value,
            [
                'type' => $type,
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => $attributeCode,
                'input' => $input,
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );

        return true;
    }

    protected function getAttributeCode($str)   {
        return strtolower(str_replace(" ", "", $str));    
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write down an observer `catalog_product_save_before` and check the attribute existence on this observer.

> etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
<event name="catalog_product_save_before">
    <observer name="check_existing_attribute" instance="FirstVendor\FirstModule\Observer\CheckAttributeBeforeObserver"/>
</event>
```

> observer/CheckAttributeBeforeObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace FirstVendor\FirstModule\Observer;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface;

class CheckAttributeBeforeObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    private $eav;


    public function __construct(
        AttributeRepositoryInterface $AttributeRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        $this->eav = $AttributeRepositoryInterface;
    }

    /**
     * check attribute existance
     *
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $attribute = $this->eav->get("catalog_product", "name");
        if(!empty($attribute->getAttributeCode())){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Command to execute this would be like:

php bin/magento create_attribute testattribute

Comment: Thanks Rahul, this seems created on command call. but my requirement is need to check before create product that attribute exist or not. If not then it should create first.

Comment: Oh gotcha. Write down an event before product save and use eavfactory to check attribute exist or not. I will write it down and send your the code.

Comment: That's great, thank you.

Comment: Hi parth, 

I have updated my comment with the updated code for an event. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks, your code will check attribute exist only it will not create in case of not exist. however I prepared logic for that. posted as answer.

Comment: Great glad that helped you. Cheers !!! Thumbs up please if it helped you.

Comment: Also, creating an attribute code can be written inside the observer as well. Also, don't use the "Config" file object directly. You should use "API" interfaces only as per standard. Don't create "Model" objects directly. This can create issues if all dependencies are not loaded.

Comment: yes, thanks for the help, this is for one time process to sync between 2 system so after that model will not require further